# Python SQLite3 listing the data in a table by a specific field

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have a table in the SQLite database. I can list the data from the application as in the photo. but I want to do this on the code and want to pull all the data accordingly. I want to do something like "top-xp".

[image: Example Photo]

I saw nothing on the tutorials or any other websites.

Comment: [Here is doc](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby) that may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
If someone has the same question, you can use "ORDER BY" like this.

```
con = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY age DESC")
```